# Setting cell value with two dates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm creating a Google Spreadsheet script with Google App scripts that interacts with Google Calendar. What I'm doing is searching for a specific Calendar event by keyword, pulling the start and end dates from that event, and then the goal is to display those two dates into *one* spreadsheet cell (mostly for readability sake). In other words, the cell should look like '07/14/19 - 07/20/19.' My code below:

```
function listEvents() {
  var id = "THE ID FOR MY CALENDAR IS HERE";   
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
  var startPeriod = new Date();
  startPeriod.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  var endPeriod = new Date(startPeriod);
  endPeriod.setDate(endPeriod.getDate() + 1000);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var gig = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  var gigName = gig.getValue(); // get the gig name so you can search for it

  var events = cal.getEvents(startPeriod, endPeriod, {search:gigName});

// find the start date of each event in the calendar
  var starttime = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) { 
    starttime.push([events[i].getStartTime()]);    
  }

  // find the end date of each event in the calendar
  var endtime = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) { 
    endtime.push([events[i].getEndTime()]); 

  var cell = sheet.getRange("E5");
  cell.setValue(starttime+endtime);
```

This is sort of working. I can set `starttime` in one cell, and `endtime` in another cell, and they look all nice and pretty ('07/14/19','07/14/19') but when I do `cell.setValue(starttime+endtime);` the formatting of that cell changes to this messy stuff `Sun Jul 14 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)Sat Jul 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)` Just to reiterate, I'd like it to look like '07/14/19-07/20/19.'

I can't tell if this is a code problem or a formatting problem. If anyone can offer some help, it'd be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Formatted dates to be concatenated inside `.setValue()`.

---

#### Solution:

Format the dates before you concatenate them in your `.setValue()`. Use the following 3 lines of code to replace the ones currently in your script.

```
//format the start time
starttime.push([Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yy")]);

//format the end time
endtime.push([Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yy")]);
```

Then your `.setValue()` should look something like this:

```
cell.setValue(starttime + ' - ' + endtime);
```

---

#### Example:

```
function listEvents() {
  var id = "THE ID FOR MY CALENDAR IS HERE";   
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
  var startPeriod = new Date();
  startPeriod.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  var endPeriod = new Date(startPeriod);
  endPeriod.setDate(endPeriod.getDate() + 1000);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var gig = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  var gigName = gig.getValue(); // get the gig name so you can search for it

  var events = cal.getEvents(startPeriod, endPeriod, {search:gigName});

  // find the start date of each event in the calendar
  var starttime = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) { 
    starttime.push([Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yy")]); 
  }

  // find the end date of each event in the calendar
  var endtime = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) { 
    endtime.push([Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yy")]);
  }

  var cell = sheet.getRange("E5");
  cell.setValue(starttime + ' - ' + endtime);
```

---

#### Reference:

1. [`Utilities.formatDate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the Utilities Service... There is a "Format Date" method there that will allow you to format the date to whatever you want it to look like.